# How to take count variable inside ForEach Loop

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

help please get count variable from nested ForEach Loop, and how to use it inside SwiftUI code (for example, like @Struct var)

```
  VStack {
            // Loop of Goals with Task
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack() {
                    ForEach(goals, id: \.self) {goal in
                        VStack{
                            Text(goal.wrappedName)
                                .padding(.all)
                            Spacer()
                            ForEach(goal.taskArray, id: \.self) { task in
                                Text(task.wrappedName)
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.1, height: 500,
                           alignment: .topLeading)
                    .background(Color.pink)
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .animation(.spring())
                }
                .frame(alignment: .center)
            }
```

I'm try to use *var taskCount = task.wrappedName.count*, but don't have idea how to use around code (Have error: Initialization of variable 'taskCount' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it)
[image: how to count]

Comment: Not clear where/how do you want to use `task.wrappedName.count`. Would you elaborate more?

Comment: or where you try to create `taskCount` and where you want to use it.

Comment: ...want to use below,  in .frame(height:   > if count <=0 { height = 100} else {height = 500}

Comment: So it's not the size of taskName but of the array you want to use.

Comment: Yes, how many task I'm have in goal (CoreData One-To-Many Relationships), and how to use this Int in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

....So it's not the size of taskName but of the array you want to use. – Joakim Danielson... was a correct answer

```
Text("\(goal.taskArray.count)")
```